# Fortify - How to customise verification / password reset emails?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-mail, laravel-fortify

I'm in the process of implementing fortify into my app. I'm really confused about customising the default emails that are produced when you hit the password-reset / verifty-email routes?

I could edit them in vendor but that going to cause me an issue every time I update.

There must be a hook to provide an alternative email template.

Unfortnatly I cant find any documentation that explains how its done.

Do I need to add:

```
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{


}
```

To my user model? If so how to I generate the return verificaiton URL as its not being held in the database?

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score -12, accepted):

You can enter the directory when you use fortify `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\ Notifications\resources\views\email.blade.php` and overwrite the content and style of the email.

Notifications are by default in the directory `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail.php`

You can change the email text lines there. Similarly reset password in `ResetPassword.php`

Comment: That's a really bad answer. You should never change files in the vendor folder. An update may overwrite the changes and all the work was for nothing!
Tip: If it's just about the texts, just have a look here: https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang

Comment: Why is this marked as the selected answer? wow... any answer that says "edit x in the vendor directory" should be automatically deleted by SO the second they post it! - NEVER listen to any answer that tells you to edit something in the vendor directory.

Answer (score 8):

You can customize the password reset email by adding the following in FortifyServiceProvider

```
ResetPassword::toMailUsing(function($user, string $token) {
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Reset Password')
        ->view('emails.password_reset', [
            'user' => $user,
            'url' => sprintf('%s/users/password_reset/%s', config('app.url'), $token)
    ]);
});
```

Create a file named `resources/views/emails/password_reset.blade.php`, in this file you can use `$user` and `$url`

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution in Laravel 8.

1.) Create a Notification by command

```
php artisan make:notification ResetPasswordNotification
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;

class ResetPasswordNotification extends ResetPassword
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $token;

    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        if (static::$toMailCallback) {
            return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $this->token);
        }

        $url = url(config('app.url') . route('password.reset', [
            'token' => $this->token,
            'email' => $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset(),
        ], false));

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->view(
                'emails.reset_password', ['name'=>$notifiable->name,'url' => $url]
            )
            ->subject(Lang::get('Reset Password'));
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

2.) In the app/Models/User.php Model. Add below method.

```
   public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }
```

3.) Now create an email template in views/emails/reset_password.blade.php

```
Hi {{ $name }}, Please reset your password here. Click on the below link to reset the password.
 <a href="{{ $url }}">RESET</a>
```